# How can I install Powershell on Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2008?

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, powershell

I am running the **stand-alone version of Hyper-V, Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2008**, and would like to install Powershell. Ill be using it to use the Management Library script.

How can I do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Doesn't appear to be supported:
http://www.microsoft.com/hyper-v-server/en/us/faq.aspx

There is a codeplex project that has vbscripts for most functions:
http://hvs2008ui.codeplex.com/

But it looks to be sunsetted.

Can't you just use remote administration tools from a workstation to perform the tasks that you need powershell for?

Comment: I am already using the MMC for some remote administration, but its for certain things like if a VM is stuck in 'stopping' mode, among others. Just thought it would be a cool set of resources to have.
BTW - if you post this as answer ill reward you with the answer, if not im going to answer myself. Thx,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from comment:

Doesn't appear to be supported: http://www.microsoft.com/hyper-v-server/en/us/faq.aspx There is a codeplex project that has vbscripts for most functions: http://hvs2008ui.codeplex.com/
But it looks to be sunsetted. Can't you just use remote administration tools from a workstation to perform the tasks that you need powershell for?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this specific scenario, but you should be able to remotely manage this computer using PowerGUI.  PowerGUI is an MMC-like console built on top of PowerShell. It uses WMI to remotely manage services, processes, Hyper-V servers, event logs, and a bunch of other stuff plus it's completely customizable.  To use Hyper-V you'll have to download the Hyper-V PowerPack from the PowerPack library (it's an optional component that doesn't come with the core product), but it should allow you to do a lot remotely and the scripts behind it are all open source so you can see how it works.  Oh, and it's free too.  You can download PowerGUI here: http://powergui.org.  And you can download the Hyper-V PowerPack here: http://www.powergui.org/entry.jspa?externalID=2142&categoryID=290.  If you want to see a screencast showing how it works first, particularly for Hyper-V, you can watch this one: http://www.powergui.org/shares/powergui/sbin/docs/Introduction_to_the_HyperV_PowerPack/Introduction_to_the_HyperV_PowerPack.html

Like I said though, I haven't specifically tested this with standalone Hyper-V, but PowerShell is not required on the Hyper-V server for this to work, just WMI, so this should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade Hyper-V Server 2008 R2.  Then, pick "Configure Remote Management" followed by "Enable Windows PowerShell" from the Server Configuration menu.