# How to manage Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 from Windows XP/Server 2003?

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

We currently have several VMs running under Virtual Server 2005 SP1.  I would like to move these to Hyper-V Server 2008 R2.  However, we only have Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 machines at present - and that is unlikely to change in the time-frame I need.

All of the tools I have seen so far to manage Hyper-V Server require Vista, or Windows 7, or a full Server 2008 machine.

1. Are there any tools that will work on Windows XP/Server 2003 to manage the Hyper-V Server?
2. Can everything necessary (e.g. creating VMs/virtual hard drives, mounting .iso as virtual cd drive, starting/stopping vms, etc) be accomplished via the Hyper-V Server commandline?
3. Where is a good reference for the Hyper-V commandline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 -

- A couple things come to mind.  Perhaps you can run Vista in a local PC virtual.  The justification is server mgmt is a vista+ only proposition.
- You could install the tools in as remote desktop terminal services apps using a WIn2k8 virtual(we do this).

2 - Yes.    As you work in Virtual machine manager, you can see the Powershell code behind each task.  That's prob. a good starting place for learning

3- [I assume Technet will have all this. Here's an MS presentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/cc952342.aspx)

Comment: For enabling powershell on Hyper-V server:

http://blogs.msdn.com/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2009/02/10/enabling-powershell-on-hyper-v-server-2008-r2.aspx

Comment: I do number 1 with a Vista VM. Works great!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Powergui with the Hyper-V powerpack to perform certain tasks.
(via [Poshoholic](https://serverfault.com/users/11883/poshoholic), and [an earlier thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/59610/how-can-i-install-powershell-on-microsoft-hyper-v-server-2008/59707#59707) I posted)